# Make a shell script with sudo-level operations accessible to others

Tags: linux, bash, sudo

On this particular Linux server, we have a directory on which people can add certain files and we want those files to be owned by a particular user, editable by a specific group, and not viewable to public. Right now, what I have to do is to occasionally run `sudo chown this_user:that_group /foo/bar/*.ext; sudo chmod 750 /foo/bar/*.ext` from the command line. I would prefer if I could turn this into a command-line program that other users could invoke, including those who don't have `sudo` access. Imagine a program called `/usr/bin/fixpermissions` which would run the above `chown` and `chmod` commands and return a success message.

How should I write this script so that it wouldn't ask for a password for the sudo part? And how can I make it available to other users (is putting it in `/usr/bin/` sufficient or appropriate)?

Answer (score 0):

That's not so much a question of "How to write the script", but rather of "How to make it usable via `sudo`".

The canonical location for the script would be `/usr/local/bin` ...

To achieve the "execute as sudo w/o password" I'd create a separate sudoers file:

```
sudo visudo -f /etc/sudoers.d/fixpermissions
```

with the following content:

```
%group ALL = NOPASSWD:  /usr/local/bin/fixpermissions
```

Obviously adjust names of files and groups to match your personal preferences and existing setup.

Careful with creating the sudoers file above w/ other means than visudo - you might end up locking yourself out of the box if you save a file with syntax errors (visudo will check it for validity on exit and prompt you to fix if it's borked).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. While this gets the work done, I was hoping for a different solution. Let me explain. When I install a package from Linux repos, that program will have access to run operations that normally would need sudo access. Obviously, I use sudo when installing it; but after that, the program (e.g. a deamon) can do administrative stuff without needing a password every time. How is that achieved? How can I turn my bash script into a package that can be "installed" on Linux, or replicate that effect even without packaging?